# Unable to show a DIV when a asp:button is within an accordian pane

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm not able to figure out, I have a button within an accordianPane and onClientClick to display a div does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my  button

```
    <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" 
    FadeTransitions="true" TransitionDuration="300" FramesPerSecond="50" 
    Width="292px" Height="199px">
 <Panes>
  <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
  <Header>Business Services</Header>
  <Content>
  <asp:Button ID="btnBusiness" runat="server" Text="Business Services"    OnClientClick="showDiv('showBusiness');"
    Height="25px" Width="200px"/>
  </Content>
```

Now I have a div on the same page

```
 <div id="showBusiness"  runat="server"  style="margin-left:65px; display:none" >
```

There is a table here

MY Javascript is simple

```
function showDiv(id) {


  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
```

}

OnClientClick does nothing. Is it because the asp button is in an accordianpane ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the runat="server" tag. Server side id's are generated, in this case it might be something like "Container_showBusiness".

```
<div id="showBusiness"  style="margin-left:65px; display:none" >
```

And change OnClientClick="showDiv('showBusiness');" to:

```
 OnClientClick="showDiv('showBusiness'); return false;"
```

Hope this helps!